# JSXで { を表示させたい

Tags: react-jsx

ReactJS中のJSXの中の { を表示させたいのですが、どのようにすればよいですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScriptの文字列を使います。例えば以下のようにするとdiv要素の中に`{`と表示されます。

```
<div>{"{"}</div>
```